# JSON Seralization returns nil if I try to cast it as anything else

Tags: json, swift, nsjsonserialization

Im having trouble parsing this json object. I'm able to parse it into Any. But if I try to cast it as an NSDictionary or anything it else it returns nil. Can anyone help me? Ive consulted several questions and they all give the same nil result.

```
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    if let reponse = response {
        print(reponse)
    }
    if let data = data {
        //print(data)

        do{

          //  let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])


            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:.allowFragments)

                // do stuff here

            //  accountJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

            print("\(json)") // This one prints .

            let accountJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

            print("trying to print accountjson")
            print("\(accountJson)") // this one doesnt. 




        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }

}
task.resume()
```

The first print statement works and results in the following code in the terminal.

```
(
    {
    "__v" = 0;
    "_id" = 59cba54406e2661530c1aa6e;
    pass = ra;
    type = ra;
    username = NikRa;
}
)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting JSON back from the server that you query?  What's the link and parameters?  Test that.

Comment: It seems from the bottom code snippet that he does get JSON back. It doesn't cast to NSDictionary (which it shouldn't).

Comment: If you add `print(type(of: json))` you can find out what the type you're working with is.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Guys I actually did figure it out. I had to cast it as an array within an array.

```
let accountJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as?  [[String: Any]]
```